# Completely remove and reinstall mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, uninstallation

I managed to bork my installation of it while trying to uninstall it. I installed via Muon (Kubuntu), and attempted uninstallation the same way.

I tried apt-get install/remove (on both mysqlserver and mysql), then tried manually removing files, but it just doesn't work. Somewhere it's determining not to regenerate its configs and not reinstall like a fresh install would.

How do i just get rid of everything mysql-related? I'd like to start fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to copy a default mysql.cnf (obtained via googling) into the /etc/mysql directory. It created debian versions of the config while using "apt-get install mysql-server-5.1", so i'm assuming the installation i was trying to do was just bad. Should have gone rpm i guess.

However using purge DID remove a few other files i didn't know about, so it did help. +1

Answer (score 5):

`apt-get purge PACKAGENAME` should completely remove a package including its configurations. Maybe this works better.

Comment: Just tried it, still doesn't work. Tried every combination of purge and remove and hand-removing files and folders, but i cannot get it to just install normally like it did when i first got it. It's starting to look as if i need to flatten the box to remove it :/

Comment: You could try `dpkg-reconfigure PACKAGENAME`

Answer (score 2):

`remove` leaves behind configuration files. You need to use `purge` instead. (`purge` works on both `apt-get(8)` and `dpkg(8)`.)